# php curl sending data from one iframe to another

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I need to use cURL to send data from one iframe to another. My code is:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>New Web Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="postback.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="send"/>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <iframe name="test" src="postback.php" width="200" height="200"></iframe>postback
        <iframe name="test2" src="replay.php" width="200" height="200"></iframe>replay
    </body> 
</html>
```

and two iframes code:
postback iframe:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["variable"])){
    $var1 = $_POST["variable"];

        $url = 'http://localhost/xss/replay.php';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $parameters = 'variable2='.$var1;
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

}
else echo 'w8';
?>
```

replay iframe:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["variable2"])){
    $var1 = $_POST["variable2"];

    echo $var1;
}
else echo 'w8';
?>
```

and in this case I get response from secound iframe (replay.php) to new page instead of print variable 2 to secound iframe. How can I change it? I would add that I cant use JavaScript/AJAX/jQuery ect. only server side scripting

Comment: if I understand what you are asking the problem might be the fact that you are expecting to affect with an curl call from the first iframe the content of the second one. But on the call you are using a totally separate instance of that script, not the one that it is displayed.

Comment: yes its exactly what I wanna to do. I wanna fire button in iframe1 and see result (echo) in iframe2. The problem might be, that each iframes are on different domains.

Comment: you will get the output from that second url in the curl call.. so you don't need a different iframe for it.. just display its initial state in the first (and only iframe) and display the curl response after the call

Comment: @mishu did you read my post? I have to write data somehow to secound iframe by server side, cause iframes are in **diferent domains** so JS is not a good choice.

Comment: where do you see any JS reference? I was just talking about the curl call and its response (using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER). if you think that my answer is not what you need you can just ignore it. yes, I read your post to give an opinion that might help and I understood that you are working with two separate servers from your previous question where I suggested jsonp to you as an alternative to ajax that works using two servers but you decided it's not what you need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this server side, you might be better off using javaScript to submit the form to the iFrame, it could be done easily by changing the iframe src to postback.php?variable=send and using $_GET[''] parameters on the server side.

I dont think you can achieve what you are looking for using curl

Comment: it could be good, but as i wrote before iframes are on *different domains* so becouse of XSS i have to use server side scripting.

Comment: @Krystian: I don't think Hank was talking about ajax (that is limited by the cross domain policy). He said that you can just submit the form (a plain form submit doesn't have this kind of limitation)